# Huge margin created from UL element blocks out other divs

Tags: html, css, html-lists, margin, spacing

I created a basic UL element that is set to display inline (basic navigation bar at the top of the website). I created another div for a search bar, which is set to float right of the UL element, but for some reason floats under the navigation div. Upon checking my elements, I noticed that the UL element has a margin that takes up all remaining space to the left and right of it, although I have not specifically assigned a margin to it. Am I missing something? I would be thankful for an answer to this problem, note that I am fairly new to web programming so excuse me if I missed something obvious!

```css
#nav_bar{
  height: 3.5rem;
  border-top: 2px solid $theme_grey;
  border-bottom: 2px solid $theme_grey;
  background-color: $theme_dark_grey;
}

#nav_bar ul{
  color: #FFF;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.8rem 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  width: 50%;
}

#nav_bar li{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 4rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

#nav_bar img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#nav_bar a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#nav_bar a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: $link-color;
}

#nav_bar a span{
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

#nav_bar #search_engine
{
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
}

#nav_bar #search_bar
{
  border: 0.2rem solid $theme_grey;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.5rem;
  outline: none;
}

#nav_bar #search_bar:hover{
  border: 0.2rem solid #6666FF;
}

#nav_bar #search_btn
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_bar">
      <ul>
        <a href="#"><li><img src="images/icons8-Home-32.png" class="home_icon"></img><span>Home</span></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li><img src="images/icons8-Chevron Up-32.png" class="chevron_icon"><span>Popular</span></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li><img src="images/Path.png"><span>Trending</span></li></a>
        <li><img src="images/icons8-Detective-32.png"></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- "search.php" page to display search results -->
      <div id="search_engine">
      <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="search_bar" placeholder="Search..." value="" maxlength="25" autocomplete="off" onmousedown="" onblur="" />
        <input type="submit" id="search_btn" value="Go!" />
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the `margin` or `padding` on `ul` may be the default browser style...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating an element left or right causes the elements that *follow*, to wrap the floated element. Your search bar is not going settle beside your navigation because the search bar is placed *after* the navigation, not *before*. Try setting `float:left` to `#nav_bar ul` as shown. I took the liberty of changing the color of `a` from white.

```css
#nav_bar{
  height: 3.5rem;
  border-top: 2px solid $theme_grey;
  border-bottom: 2px solid $theme_grey;
  background-color: $theme_dark_grey;
}

#nav_bar ul{
  color: #FFF;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.8rem 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}

#nav_bar li{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 4rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

#nav_bar img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#nav_bar a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav_bar a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: $link-color;
}

#nav_bar a span{
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

#nav_bar #search_engine
{
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
}

#nav_bar #search_bar
{
  border: 0.2rem solid $theme_grey;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.5rem;
  outline: none;
}

#nav_bar #search_bar:hover{
  border: 0.2rem solid #6666FF;
}

#nav_bar #search_btn
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_bar">
      <ul>
        <a href="#"><li><img src="images/icons8-Home-32.png" class="home_icon"></img><span>Home</span></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li><img src="images/icons8-Chevron Up-32.png" class="chevron_icon"><span>Popular</span></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li><img src="images/Path.png"><span>Trending</span></li></a>
        <li><img src="images/icons8-Detective-32.png"></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- "search.php" page to display search results -->
      <div id="search_engine">
      <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="search_bar" placeholder="Search..." value="" maxlength="25" autocomplete="off" onmousedown="" onblur="" />
        <input type="submit" id="search_btn" value="Go!" />
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You don't need `float:right` on the search element for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using flexboxes to avoid floats.

```css
#nav_bar {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

#search_engine {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <a href="#">
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/25" class="home_icon"><span>Home</span></li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/25" class="chevron_icon"><span>Popular</span></li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/25"><span>Trending</span></li>
    </a>
  </ul>
  <!-- "search.php" page to display search results -->
  <div id="search_engine">
    <form action="search.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="search_bar" placeholder="Search..." value="" maxlength="25" autocomplete="off" onmousedown="" onblur="" />
      <input type="submit" id="search_btn" value="Go!" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```